# Error while creating unique clustered index in view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, unique, clustered-index

I wanted to create unique clustered index in view by name.

This is how I created the view

```
create view vWTotalsalesbyProduct
with schemabinding
as
    select 
        Name,
        Sum(Isnull(Unitprice * QuantitySold, 0)) as TotalSales,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Totaltransation 
    from 
        dbo.product P 
    join
        dbo.tblproductcount C on P.productID = C.productID 
    group by 
        Name
```

[image]

and this is how I created unique clustered index

```
create unique clustered index UIX_vWTotalsalesbyProductName 
on vWTotalsalesbyProduct(Name)
```

But I get an error

> Column 'Name' in table 'vWTotalsalesbyProduct' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Help me solve it

Comment: So what is the datatype of the `Name` column in the base table?

Comment: varchar(max) is datatype for Name

Comment: Can you change it to a saner datatype? I can't imagine a name needs to support lengths of 2GB

Comment: You cannot use varchar(max) as a key column in an index

Comment: A solution would be to declare your key as nvarchar(20)

Comment: Considering that your screenshot shows that `[Name]` has values such as `Books`, `newspapers`, etc, why a `varchar(MAX)`? Do you *really* need to be able to store 2GB of characters (that's 2,147,483,647 characters!) in that field..?

Comment: You'd better use the productID field as a clustered index.

Comment: The max size for a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is 2 GByte of storage or approx. 1 billion characters. Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* is a 1'440 page book, containing about 600'000 words - so that might be 6 million characters - well rounded up. So you could stick about 166 copies of the entire *War and Peace* book into each `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column. Do you ***REALLY*** need your `Name` column to be ***THIS LARGE*** ?!?!?!?

Comment: So It seems I can't use varchar(max) as data type in  key column in an index...nvarchar(20) is solution..Thanks

Comment: @Awesome varchar(*max*) is a different type - the actual data is stored outside the row. When you retrieve the row the server has to perform extra work to look up that blob. Different buffers will be used for varchar and `varchar(max)`. This means queries that return `varchar(max)` will be slower too. You shouldn't use it as an open-ended varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique Constraint can hold up to 8000 bytes per row. So if the maximum length of the column allows to store more than 8000 bytes, you will get error.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp
(
    Name VARCHAR(901) UNIQUE
)
```

This code gave me the following warning

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'UQ__Temp__737584F64FD1D5C8' has maximum length of 5000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

While this works fine

```
create TABLE dbo.Temp
(
    Name VARCHAR(900) UNIQUE
)
```

If You Use VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) You  Will get this Exact error

```
create TABLE dbo.Temp
(
    Name VARCHAR(max) UNIQUE
)
```

[image]

So make sure that the maximum allowable size of the column `Name` is less than 900 bytes

Comment: The error is about the data type, not the size. `(n)varchar(max)` is a different data type with different storage

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos that's why he gets just warning instead of error

Comment: @marc_s in the *question* the error is `is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.` and the type is varchar(max)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin are we reading a different question or was the question edited to something completely different? `Column 'Name' in table 'vWTotalsalesbyProduct' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index`

Comment: @marc_s `varchar(max)` is a *blob* type. It's stored *outside* the page. The table contains only a pointer to the actual data location. The same restriction, for the same reasons, applied when we used text/ntext.

Comment: The updated answer is the same as before. It's the *type* that changed, not the size. `varchar(max)` is a blob type that's stored *outside* the row, with only a pointer stored in the row itself. That's why you can't have an index, especially a clustered index on it - what good would be to sort by pointer value? When you specified a size, you changed it to a string that's stored *inside* the row.

Comment: There are other differences too, that affect performance, caching. It's one thing to load one row or more rows that contains all field data, it's another thing to have to look up the blobs.